# How to type this math symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, mathjax

I've got to type this symbol in my article. I've searched through Internet but haven't seen anything about how to write it in TeX command. It is perhaps rarely seen or used. But I really need to use it in my article:
[image]

And below are the packages I am using:
[image]
Can you help me? Best regards!

Comment: @darthbith sorry but I don't have something like Detexify. Also, I searched through all the jax command for math symbols but couldn't find this one.

Comment: Detexify is a website... Are you not able to access it? Did you check the other links in that question?

Comment: @darthbith my apologies. I thought that was a software. I'm checking the link in the first answer it should be very helpful.  Thanks for your resource!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ \in \mbox{and} \ni \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The symbol can be found in "Table 139: Letter-like Symbols" of [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: You can create your equation in the "StackExchange" Mathematics site and then copy pasted here. For example in this site: math.stackexchange.com/questions/321736/… I copy/pasted this ∑ simbol or this: ∫xπdC(x)dx as you see is not perfect. The x should be down in the integral and the π up, but is a good start. I think